# When converting xml to json , several objects name change to "@attributes"

Tags: php, json, xml

I read this article.

https://qiita.com/yasumodev/items/74a73ed4b3f1dd45edb8

And I did the same thing.

```
// XML(RSSなど)を取得
$strXml = file_get_contents("./doc.xml");
// XML⇒JSONに変換
$strJson = xml_to_json($strXml);
// 出力
echo $strJson;

//**********************************
// XML ⇒ JSONに変換する関数
//**********************************
function xml_to_json($xml)
{
    // コロンをアンダーバーに（名前空間対策）
    $xml = preg_replace("/<([^>]+?):([^>]+?)>/", "<$1_$2>", $xml);
    // プロトコルのは元に戻す
    $xml = preg_replace("/_\/\//", "://", $xml);
    // XML文字列をオブジェクトに変換（CDATAも対象とする）
    $objXml = simplexml_load_string($xml, NULL, LIBXML_NOCDATA);
    // 属性を展開する
    xml_expand_attributes($objXml);
    // JSON形式の文字列に変換
    $json = json_encode($objXml, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    // "\/" ⇒ "/" に置換
    return preg_replace('/\\\\\//', '/', $json);
}

//**********************************
// XMLタグの属性を展開する関数
//**********************************
function xml_expand_attributes($node)
{
    if($node->count() > 0) {
        foreach($node->children() as $child)
        {
            foreach($child->attributes() as $key => $val) {
                $node->addChild($child->getName()."@".$key, $val);
            }
            xml_expand_attributes($child); // 再帰呼出
        }
    }
}
```

But in this way , several objects name change to "@attributes".

I want the original object name here(T_T)

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you `json_encode()` XML with attributes, this will create the `@attributes` elements your getting.  The only way round this is to remove them as you expand them.  I've changed the routine, the first thing is that I've put the part that processes the attributes first, this ensures that the root node gets processed as well.

The main thing is that I've changed the way it works to use XPath to retrieve the attributes, this then encodes them as you have, but also allows you to remove the attribute from the original node (using `unset($attribute[0]);`)...

```
function xml_expand_attributes($node)
{

    foreach ($node->xpath("@*") as $attribute) {
        $node->addChild($node->getName()."@".$attribute->getName(), (string)$attribute);
        unset($attribute[0]);
    }
    if($node->count() > 0) {
        foreach($node->children() as $child)
        {
            xml_expand_attributes($child); // 再帰呼出
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You helped me so much.